# Floating point exceptions in C++ on Windows / MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, floating-point, c++17

On Linux one can install a function to be called in the event of a floating point exception in the following manner:

```
// 1. define MyFunction
void MyFunction(int signal) { /*...*/ }

// 2. install MyFunction as SIGFPE signal handler
struct sigaction sa = {};
sa.sa_handler = MyFunction;
sigaction(SIGFPE, &sa, nullptr);

// 3. raise SIGFPE on FE_DIVBYZERO or FE_INVALID
feenableexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO | FE_INVALID);
```

What is the equivalent code to install `MyFunction` on Windows / MSVC ?

(I've heard that [`_control87`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/control87-controlfp-control87-2?view=msvc-160) can be used in some similar fashion, how precisely should it be called to have the same effect as the above?)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/floating-point-exceptions and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fp-specify-floating-point-behavior

Comment: And the Windows Exception would then be converted into a function call via [`AddVectoredContinueHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-addvectoredcontinuehandler).